# Adding elements to a column in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, append

I was wondering how I could append elements to matrix through the column. What I mean by this is that if I have a matrix:

A=

```
a
b
c
d
```

I want to add an element e at the bottom of the matrix A. So that I will have

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

where a,b,... can be vectors as well.

I am trying to implement this in a for - loop.

Thank you.

Comment: If you know from the start the number of rows/columns in your matrix, it should way faster to create an empty matrix at first and in the loop select and fill the specific row. Perhaps, you could post more details on what you're trying to do since there is a high chance that you could avoid some bottlenecks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rbind`

```
A <- rbind(A, e).
```

It could get slow in a loop if your matrix is big. If you know the size in advance, it is better to preallocate the matrix, and then assign rows `A[i,] <- e`, for example.

Comment: If I try to do:
A[i,] <- e
I get the error: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: dimensions have to match, pls add an example that illustrates the error to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far Andrei. I wish I could upvote you.

What I have right now is a N by M matrix (lets call this A). I want to take out each each column from this matrix A, trim off the last two rows and then use that to make a column vector (lets call this B) of all the elements in the matrix A. 

Therefore, the first element (row) of B will be the first column of A (minus the last two rows) and the second row of B will have the second column of A. So we will essentially have a really long column vector. 

Thus, the dimensions of B will be N*M by 1. Thanks

Comment: So you remove last to rows of A, and then concatenate all the columns, wouldn't the length of vector B be (N-2)*M ?

Comment: I actually just figured it out. I removed the last two rows of A by deleting the last two rows A<-A[1:M,]  and then doing A <-as.vector(A). 
Thanks anyways, Andrei. It helped a lot. One day I will return to upvote you (when I can)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert matrix to a dataframe. Then you can easily add additional rows. You can convert it back to matrix if needed:

```
mm
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 [2,]    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9    10
 [3,]    0    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16    18    20
 [4,]    0    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24    27    30
 [5,]    0    4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32    36    40
 [6,]    0    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40    45    50
 [7,]    0    6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48    54    60
 [8,]    0    7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56    63    70
 [9,]    0    8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64    72    80
[10,]    0    9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72    81    90
[11,]    0   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80    90   100
> dd = data.frame(mm)
> dd
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11
1   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
2   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9  10
3   0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16  18  20
4   0  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24  27  30
5   0  4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32  36  40
6   0  5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40  45  50
7   0  6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48  54  60
8   0  7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56  63  70
9   0  8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64  72  80
10  0  9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72  81  90
11  0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80  90 100
> dd[12,]=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,9)
> dd
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11
1   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
2   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9  10
3   0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16  18  20
4   0  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24  27  30
5   0  4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32  36  40
6   0  5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40  45  50
7   0  6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48  54  60
8   0  7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56  63  70
9   0  8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64  72  80
10  0  9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72  81  90
11  0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80  90 100
12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9   8   9
> as.matrix(dd)
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11
1   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
2   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9  10
3   0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16  18  20
4   0  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24  27  30
5   0  4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32  36  40
6   0  5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40  45  50
7   0  6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48  54  60
8   0  7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56  63  70
9   0  8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64  72  80
10  0  9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72  81  90
11  0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80  90 100
12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9   8   9
>
```